# i have problem in understand kernel threads ..what actually is kernel threads?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, kernel

what do kernel threads really have to do with user process? What actually mapping means? is it the programmer who selects which user thread to map with which kernel thread?

Comment: This is a *very* unspecific question. "kernel thread" can have several (related, but not identical) meanings. Could you give us some context?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question:

CPU only runs kernel thread, because kernel sees only kernel threads and the kernel manages CPU scheduling. If a user process wants to performance a task, one of the user process threads would be mapped to a kernel thread so it can be scheduled by kernel and ran by CPU.
Programmers do not need to worry about mapping the user threads to kernel threads. Maybe in some systems, programmer could bind a user thread to a kernel thread, but I am not sure if this is possible.